# How to force two users to autologin at boot into two separate xfce sessions?

Tags: xfce4

On boot, I would like more than one user to be auto logged in on virtual terminals.

Answer (score 1):

Try to install KDE Display Manager for X11

```
# apt-get install -y kdm
```

You need to modify configuration file:

/etc/kde4/kdm/kdmrc

```
[X-:0-Core]
ServerVT=8
AutoLoginEnable=true
AutoLoginAgain=true
AutoLoginDelay=10
AutoLoginUser=user1
AutoLoginPass=pass1

[X-:1-Core]
ServerVT=9
AutoLoginEnable=true
AutoLoginAgain=true
AutoLoginDelay=10
AutoLoginUser=user2
AutoLoginPass=pass2
```

For each user you should specify the desktop manager:

```
# cat /home/user{1,2}/.dmrc
[Desktop]
Session=enlightenment

[Desktop]
Session=cinnamon
```